# MySQL can't login the 2nd time with error message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I just set up mysql server 8.0 on my local machine. The first time login was fine and I created my database and everything, but since I wanted to load local files so I exited and did `mysql -u root -p --local-infile databasename;`. When I did that it gave me `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'databasename;'`. Then I tried to login using `mysql -u root -p` to check the database but I got this error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I tried to restart mysqld but new error message pops up. And I tried to reset the root password it didn't work either.

So I tried to reinstall mysql. The exact same thing happened. The first time login was fine, but when I exit and did `--local-infile databasename` it said `Unknown database 'databasename;` again.

Could someone help me with this issue? Thank you! I'm using the widows system.

Comment: You're supposed to replace `databasename` with the name of your actual database.

Comment: Yeah, I did that...

Comment: Couple of information needed. Powershell or command prompt? Which version of windows? Legacy login or new login? (probably not caps lock on?) Just tried it with my mysql server 8.0 and after doing mysql -u root -p it prompts me for the password and I put it in and it authenticates and opens mysql.exe successfully. On windows 10, legacy login support, powershell. You can try reinstalling and use the legacy login support(if not already) to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend installing [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), which is the "official" MySQL GUI.  It's not that great, but it makes troubleshooting these sort of problems much easier.

Next, If you can actually connect to your localhost instance with workbench, run this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourPasswordHere'
```

If not, try reinstalling MySQL again and see if you can connect.